# Counting Vowels in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I have done this successfully in Java and C++ but can't figure it out in Swift. Here is my C++ code:

```
int count_vowels (string input)
{
  int position = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
    char ch;
    ch = input[i];

      if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u'){
          position++;
      }

  }
  return position;
}
```

Again I'm just trying to iterate through a string, counting the values that are true in the if statement and returning the position(how many there are).

Is there any way to convert this to swift syntax.

I figured it out:

for char in vowels.characters{

```
            if char == ("a") || char == ("e") || char == ("i") || char == ("o") || char == ("u") {

                count++
            }
    }
```

Thanks everybody for there help and posts I was pulling my hair out on this one.

Thanks again

Comment: you can convert it 1:1 - not elegant but possible

Comment: I figured it out here is the code if anyone wants to give it a once over.

Comment: You should give Regex a try !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
extension String {
    var numberOfVowels: Int {
        let vowels = "aeiou"
        let vowelsSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: vowels)
        let strippedComponents = lowercaseString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(vowelsSet)
        let stripped = strippedComponents.joinWithSeparator("")
        return characters.count - stripped.characters.count
    }
}

"Hello".numberOfVowels
```

Comment: Do you know if the run time on this is faster then configuring an array with the arguments to the string in question?

Comment: This is definitely not a performance optimized solution.  I'm not sure the alternative you're referring to, but I can't guarantee that this is fast.  If you're doing huge amounts of string processing, this isn't the way to go.  If you're making an app and want a readable, robust solution, this is one way you could go :)

Comment: I tried this in swift 2.1 playground and joinWithSeperator doesn't work and also tried join but that did not work either. Any ideas on what Swift 2.1 likes I'm searching around currently.

Comment: I just tried this on Xcode 7, and 7.1 beta 1 and its working fine.

Comment: Interesting I will try it again and let you know. My beta has been acting funny I'll shutdown and restart and see what happens.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I don't know Swift but....

You should be able to use Swift's higher level features to accomplish this more succinctly. For example, the vowel characters don't change within your function so they can be represented as a Swift Set:

```
var vowelCount = 0
var vowels = Set(["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"])
```

Then test if each input character is a member of the set and increment the count if it is:

```
for ch in input {
  if (vowels.contains(ch)) {
    vowelCount += 1
  }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment I like that you used a set.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that you should show what it is you've tried in Swift so we can provide guidance on what may be broken. That being said, I did a quick conversion. It may not be the best, but here you go

```
import Cocoa

let vowels: [Character] = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

func count_vowels(input: String) -> Int {
    var vowelCount: Int = 0
    for ch in input.lowercaseString.characters {
        if (vowels.contains(ch)) {
            vowelCount++
        }
    }
    return vowelCount
}
```

With this, `print(count_vowels("Hello world"))` prints out `3`

EDIT:
Modified my answer based on [the answer from Tom Hicks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32770069/939872). It definitely gets rid of the ugly `if` statement and makes the code easier to read. I declare the vowels list outside of the function so that it isn't being generated every time you call the function.

Comment: Sorry I didn't leave anything I had tried basically what you did here but instead of the for ch in input.lowercaseString.characters. I did a for loop that was for(var i = 0; i < input.characters.count; i++{ and then did an if statement like this if input.characters.contains("a") and so on { vowels++}

Comment: If you liked the answer, please go ahead and accept it. Even if you don't accept mine, an accepted answer will be helpful to anyone else that is searching for a good way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This will work ... but its not elegent.

```
let str = "test voWeL COUNT"

let v = ["A","a","E","e","i","I","o","O","u","U"]

var vowels = 0;

for i in str.characters {
    print(i)
    if (v.contains("\(i)")) {
        vowels++
    }
}

print("Vowels \(vowels)")
```

Comment: thanks for the comment I was just about to configure an array to hold the arguments so it looks nicer thanks for the input.