# Check if a word starts with a Vowel or a Consonant

Tags: string, swift, character

I need to check if a word starts with a vowel or a consonant, something like that:

```
let word = "ciao"

if wordStartsWithVowel {
    print("Word starts with Vowel!")
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32769582/2303865

Comment: yes not the same. this one it is easier. You just need to check the first character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let vowels: [Character] = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
let word = "ciao"

if vowels.contains(word.lowercased().characters.first!) {
    print("Word starts with Vowel!")
}
```

`.lowercaseString` is important because, otherwise, uppercase vowels wouldn't be recognised as vowels.

Comment: `hour` starts with a vowel sound but it starts with an `h`.

Comment: What about `yuppie`?

Comment: I'm Italian, we never consider the English letters! (J, K, W, X, Y)

Answer (score 5):

```
extension Character {
    var isVowel: Bool { "aeiou".contains { String($0).compare(String(self).folding(options: .diacriticInsensitive, locale: nil), options: .caseInsensitive) == .orderedSame } }
}
```

---

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var startsWithVowel: Bool { first?.isVowel == true }
}
```

---

```
"ciao".startsWithVowel     // false
"Ciao".startsWithVowel     // false
"Artic".startsWithVowel    // true
"artic".startsWithVowel    // true
"Ártico".startsWithVowel   // true
"ártico".startsWithVowel   // true
```

Comment: What about `yuppie`?

Comment: This is much more complex than you think

Comment: If you take a look at the new Character properties there is no isVowel property

Comment: I don't get what you're referring to? when i run `print("yuppie".startsWithVowel)` with your extensions i get `false`.

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0221-character-properties.md