# "Self" working in switch statement, but not If statement in Swift

Tags: swift

this code works

```
extension Character {
    func isVowel() -> Bool {
        switch self {
        case "a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U":
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

but when I use an if statement it gives "cannot convert type "String" to Bool

```
extension Character {

    func isVowel() -> Bool {
        if "a", "e", "i", "o", "u" {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

}//does not work
```

I have tried adding "self" and self.asciiValue

how to properly convert the switch statement into if statement? sorry, still a beginner lol

Comment: This has nothing to do with “self not working.” `if` cannot be used with pattern matching and *multiple cases.* As explained in the duplicate, there are better solutions (such as  `contains()` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if statement should look like this:

```
if self == "a" || self == "e" || self == "i" || self == "o" || self == "u" {
  return true
} else {
  return false
}
```

Another way to do this would be:

```
func isVowel() -> Bool {
  return ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].contains(self)

  // or even shorter (by Leo Dabus):
  return "aeiou".contains(self)
}
```

Comment: Why not simply `return "aeiou".contains(self)`?

Comment: and use a computed property instead of a function `var isVowel: Bool {
        return "aeiou".contains(self)
    }`

Comment: Note that this would return false for e in `café` or for uppercase E

Comment: @LeoDabus: Good points! I've added your solution.

Comment: @wvteijlingen check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35495497/2303865